# Getting similar Cipher Text for React Native client as server side Java code

Tags: java, reactjs, react-native, aes, sha

I am new to React Native. 
The server side guy has written encryption logic in Java which goes as following

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class AES {

    @Autowired
    static AesProps props;

    private static String secretkey = "abcdefghijklmnopqhijklmnopq"; // Sample key

    private static SecretKeySpec secretKey;
    private static byte[] key;

    public static void setKey(String myKey) {
        MessageDigest sha = null;
        try {
            key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt) {
        try {
            setKey(secretkey);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I am trying to find a way to encrypt in React Native, which will give me the same cipher as above Java code. 
I went through `react-native-aes-crypto`but many things are missing. Like how to use `PKCS5PADDING` and how to do corresponding `SecretKeySpec`. 
Any help would be much appreciated.